# logstash - input file is deleted and recreated

Tags: file, input, logstash

I am using logstash to read in data to elasticsearch. I have a file I am monitoring called VpnStatsDetail.xml. This file gets created and deleted periodically (~1 second) by another process and contains another 'log' for logstash to parse. However it only reads the first modification of this file and never reads anything after that. I have played around with 'sincedb_path' and 'start_position' but to no avail. Any suggestions would be great!

```
input {
    file {
        #path => "C:/Projects/Python Projects/SolAdmin/SolAdmin/ClientConnectionsWide_*.xml"
        path => "C:/Projects/Python Projects/SolAdmin/SolAdmin/VpnStatsDetail.xml"
        start_position => beginning
        type = "vpn_details"
        #ignore_older => 0
        #sincedb_path => "NUL"
        #sincedb_path => "C:/Projects/Elastic Stack/logstash-2.3.4/logstash-2.3.4/sincedb"
        codec => multiline {
            pattern => '<rpc-reply semp-version="soltr/7_1_1">'
            negate => true
            what => "previous"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: delete the sincedb file where ever it is on your machine. For linux I use `"/dev/null"` as `sincedb_path` value. Not sure what is the value for windows.

Comment: The problem is not related to sincedb. As I mention I've played around with this setting, deleting files etc. The actual problem was that the end node was being incorrectly formatted and therefor new nodes were never recognised:

</rpc-reply>
<rpc-reply semp-version="soltr/7_1_1">

Answer (score 0):

The case is when you give path as filename logstash checks for new lines on given file. Change your `path` as:

```
path => "C:/Projects/Python Projects/SolAdmin/SolAdmin/VpnStats*"
```

if there is one file that starts with VpnStats. Now logstash will check for new files that matches the pattern and will recognize same file. And add:

```
discover_interval => 1
```

so logstash will check every second for new file.

Comment: Nope, this is incorrect. You don't need to inlude this setting. The issue was that the ending tag was not correctly formatted and therefor logstash never reaslised it was going to the next entry.